# How to stop the slideshow on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I apologize for posting something that has already been asked here few times before, but I was unable to find my answer in those posts and would really appreciate your helps!

On our page we have the following section where the options/tabs seen on LHS rotates automatically displaying their contents on the RHS (for example, in the following image the Direct TV tab is displaying a video on the RHS)

[image: screenshot of what i have on my page]

Now I need to stop/pause the slideshow when the users have their mouse over the RHS of the panel or in this case, on top of the video. Right now the tabs (on LHS) keep changing even if the video is playing....which is really annoying. This is the script I was given regarding the slideshow: http://jsfiddle.net/walahh/6RbYt/

I am struggling with few other things at this moment, and **would** really appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue. Thank you for your time and help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "mouse" appears nowhere in your JS Fiddle code.  If you want something to happen "onmouseover", then you need to hook an event handler to that event.

In essence:

```
$('#RHS').mouseEnter(pauseSlideshow())
         .mouseLeave(unpauseSlideshow());
```

except that you'll have to replace "#RHS", "pauseSlideshow", and "unpauseSlideshow" with your actual IDs/methods.

Comment: thank you for your response! can you please kindly provide me some examples or links to example/tutorial?

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will take a  look at this mouseEnter/mouseLeave events.